# Shortcode is not processed when added to option field using wp_editor

Tags: shortcode, wp-editor

I managed to add a button to TinyMCE with this code:

```
 wp_editor( get_option('piedino_plugin_var_testo'), 'piedino_plugin_var_testo_id', array(
 'wpautop'       => false,
 'media_buttons' => false,
 'textarea_name' => 'piedino_plugin_var_testo',
 'textarea_rows' => 10,
 'quicktags'=>false
) );
```

I get the content of the `wp_editor()` with this:

```
get_option('piedino_plugin_var_testo');
```

If I use a shortcode in this `wp_editor()`, when I display the content in the front end, the shortcode doesn’t work; I see `[shortcode]` instead the result of the shortcode

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress applies various filters to the content before it is output. The filter `do_shortcode` is the one that processes shortcodes.  You can apply all of the same filters to the output of your editor by using the following code:

```
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', get_option( 'piedino_plugin_var_testo' ) );
```

Here is the list of all of the filters applied to `the_content`:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'capital_P_dangit', 11 );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wptexturize'                       );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'convert_smilies',               20 );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop'                           );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'shortcode_unautop'                 );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'prepend_attachment'                );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wp_make_content_images_responsive' );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'do_shortcode', 11 ); // AFTER wpautop()
```

Comment: I don't find the accept button, sorry.